# Why can't I connect to GPU backend even with a Colab Pro account?

Tags: google-colaboratory

For the past week, I have been failing to connect to a GPU, even though I have no active sessions whatsoever.

The message that keeps getting popped is the following:

> **Cannot connect to GPU backend**
>
> You cannot currently connect to a GPU due to usage limits in Colab. Learn more
>
> As a Colab Pro subscriber you have higher usage limits than non-subscribers, but availability is not unlimited. To get the most out of Colab Pro, avoid using GPUs when they are not necessary for your work.

[image]

Note that I have a Colab Pro account.

Answer (score 4):

If you excessively use GPUs you will go over the Colab Pro quota of 24h. Then, you will be restricted from usage for *at least* 12h.

Colab Pro is better and more flexible than the free version, but it still has its limitations.

Comment: The problem is that I haven't been using GPUs for the past week. This started after the first time I tried to run CARLA on collab, I was working for like two hours and then this message prompted. Since then I am failing to connect to a GPU.
FYI:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/MichaelBosello/carla-colab/blob/master/carla-simulator.ipynb

Comment: @HarisBez I comepletely understand your frustration. I am in the same boat as you are right now. I am a Colab Pro user and facing the same notice message since last 3-4 days straight. I know I run my models for atleast 12-24 hrs but i thought that i how we suppose to train the models. In any case, I am also waiting for a resolution in this matter. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any proper solution ?