# Colab pro and GPU availability

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

I need GPU for my project. Till now I had limited use and used Colab free. Now I think I may need as much as 3 hours a day. Now it says GPU is not available because they are already taken. My question is, what effect does upgrading to Colab pro have on GPU availability? How many hours should I expect to have GPU and are these hours arbitrary chosen by me or not?
I referred [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/colab-pro-is-it-worth-the-money-32a1744f42a8) and [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545195/google-colab-pro-cannot-connect-to-gpu-backend) but no good detail about GPU availability is given.

In [Their website](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#usage-limits) they tell that these limitations vary and depends on previous usage, and a precise answer might not be even available, so even an approximated answer is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.I had the same experience that GPU is not available in colab.
Why not try [gpushare.com](https://gpushare.com) to run 3090 or 2080ti with free credit.
The platform supports the most popular machine learning frameworks,like TensorFlow and PyTorch,users can be fast to instantiate a VM image.
I think it's appropriate to accelerate your model training.